# In Eve, do any EW modules or drones work on NPCs?

Tags: eve-online

In Eve, ECM (Electronic Counter-Measures) modules (like *Jammers*), **don't work** on NPC pirates (as I once found out the hard way). But looking at EVEMon - it seems that ECM is a subset of the EW category. And there's a lot of different EW (Electronic Warfare) type of modules, like *Target Painters*, etc.

Do *any* of these EW modules work on NPCs? (Or the EW drones?) Or are NPCs just immune to everything in the EW category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of all the Electronic Warfare modules, the Target Painter is the only one that really works on NPCs, since it just increases their signature.

The others do have a slight chance to work on rats but NPCs have a tendency to cheat when it comes to EW, so it's usually not worth it.

Comment: Except sleepers, sleepers hate Ewar! Also, i believe the goal is to make NPCs more "real" similar to sleepers.

Comment: If you include propulsion jamming and cap warfare in EW then Nos will 'sort of work' (you'll  gain cap but they won't be impaired at all) and webbys still work.